# Adobe Creative SDK - Web based image editor

Tags: html, adobe

Has anyone used the Adobe Creative SDK yet?  I registered my site and received the api key and plugged into my web page.  It is extremely simple, basically copying their example and using my own image except i keep getting the following error:

*"There was a problem loading the image URI provided to the 'url' config key.  Please verify that the URI is publicly accessible, and that the image is a supported format."*

I checked the Adobe site with no luck and I have a small 354 x 384 image i am using.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Aviary Test</title>

<!-- Load Feather code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://feather.aviary.com/imaging/v3/editor.js"></script>

<!-- Instantiate Feather -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
apiKey: 'MY KEY',
theme: 'dark', // Check out our new 'light' and 'dark' themes!
tools: 'all',
appendTo: '',
onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
    var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
    img.src = newURL;
},
onError: function(errorObj) {
    alert(errorObj.message);
}
});
function launchEditor(id, src) {
featherEditor.launch({
    image: id,
    url: src
});
return false;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id='injection_site'></div>

<img id='image1' src='desert.jpg'/>

<!-- Add an edit button, passing the HTML id of the image and the public URL of the image -->
<p><input type='image' src='http://images.aviary.com/images/edit-photo.png' value='Edit photo' onclick="return launchEditor('image1', 'Desert.jpg');" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.

Everything works, but when you try to load an image from a different location you get the "there was a problem loading the image uri provided to the 'url' config key" error.

My site looks like this:

- full (full sized image folder)
- thumb (folder)
- index.html

You can see the error here: http://koffid.nl/memetests/sdk2/

When you use the Edit Photo button which uses an external URL to the image it works.
When you click on the image which uses my file structure instead of the button the error shows up.

So this doesn't work:

```html
<img id='image1' src='thumb/feather_thumb.jpg' value='Edit photo' onclick="return launchEditor('image1', 'full/feather_default.jpg');" /></p>
```

And this does work:

```html
<p><input type='image' src='http://images.aviary.com/images/edit-photo.png' value='Edit photo' onclick="return launchEditor('image1', 'http://images.aviary.com/imagesv5/feather_default.jpg');" /></p>
```

Comment: It's the expected behaviour, just append your domain + path to your file with js.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a relative url, you need to pass the full url of the image, ie. http://example.com/images/myimage.jpg